# Am I correct for this predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Is my statement correct? If it is correct, is it possible to further simplify?

$$
\neg (\forall z )(\exists!y)
[\neg P(z, y) \land Q(z, y)]
= (\exists z)(\forall y)
\big[ (P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y) ) 
\lor (\exists x)(\neg P(z, x) \land Q(z, x) \land x \neq y)\big]
$$

Comment: It's incorrect, $\exists ! x P(x)$ means, $\exists x \forall y (P(y) \iff x=y)$. Negation of unique existential is not a universal.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I think you should add $P(x)$ into that existential, to cover for the case when $P(x)$ is identically false.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz , I won't. Assume $P(x)$ to be false and see what that implies. I will let you figure out why you don't need to *explicitly* include $P(x)$ - proof left as an exercise. :)

Comment: Suppose $P\equiv \bot$  Take the given $x$ such that for all $y$, $P(x)\iff x=y$. Then for $y=x$ you have $P(x)\equiv\bot$ but $(x=x)\equiv\top$. What am I not seing? @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Yes, and... That would mean what, exactly? It would mean that there is no unique $x$ such that $P(x)$, which is precisely what we want given that $P(x)$ is false.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Yes, I started from the right hand side and contradicted the left hand side, so both are not equivalent. Anyways, I think this comment section is no the place to talk about this, since it's not relevant to the question. We can talk by chat. Just start a room and tag me, if you want.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am sorry, I won't go over that with you. That said, if you want to get a relatively comprehensive grasp of what I mean, you can refer to any logic textbook that covers natural deduction. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Close!

It's clear what you're trying to do, and it's a good idea: if it is not true that for all $z$ there is a unique $y$ such that [bla bla], then there must be at least one $z$ for which there either are no $y$ such that [bla bla] or there are at least two things for which [bla bla]

You just didn't execute this very well. Note that the pattern you need is:

$$\exists z (\text{zero things such that [bla bla]} \lor \text{at least two things such that [bla bla]})$$

Now, you figured that 'zero things such that [bla bla]' is the same as 'everything not [bla bla]', i.e. you would get $\forall y \neg$ [bla bla]. And yes, with [bla bla] being $[\neg P(z, y) \land Q(z, y)]$, you get that $\neg$ [bla bla] amounts to $[P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)]$, and thus 'zero things such that [bla bla]' can be formalized as $\forall z \ [P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)]$

OK, so far so good ... but now you made a mistake. For the 'two things that [bla bla] you need two quantifiers $y$ and $x$, but you figured that since you already are using a $y$ quantifier for the 'nothing bla bla', you can just use that one as long as you extend the scope of it, i.e. you need to 'take out' the $y$ quantifier. In effect, you tried to go from:

$$\exists z (\forall y \ [P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)] \lor \text{at least two things such that [bla bla]})$$

to:

$$\exists z \forall y \ ( [P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)] \lor \text{one more thing such that [bla bla]})$$

OK, so you made 2 mistakes here in pulling out the $\forall y$:

1. You need an existential $\exists y$ for the 'at least two things ...', rather than a universal
2. Even if a universal was used in the second half, you still cannot pull a universal over a disjunction. That is, $\forall y \phi \lor \forall \psi)$ is not equivalant to $\forall y (\phi \lor \psi)$

OK, so keep the $\forall y$ inside, and introduce a new $y$, but with an existential:

$$\exists z (\forall y \  [P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)] \lor \exists y \exists x ...)$$

A final mistake you made was that you never specified that in the second half, the $y$ is something that has [bla bla]. That is, you specified that [bla bla] is true for $x$, but not for $y$. So, what you need is

$$\exists z (\forall y \  [P(z, y) \lor \neg Q(z, y)] \lor \exists y \exists x [\neg P(z, y) \land Q(z, y) \land \neg P(z, x) \land Q(z, x) \land x \neq y])$$